# MySQL Query: Return a single line of permissions per user id

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to return each user "uid" and with their category id "catid"'s in columns, how do I return each catid in multiple columns instead of multiple rows?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7f35/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read on `GROUP_CONCAT`.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

```
SELECT UID, GROUP_CONCAT(CATID) FROM phpc_category_permissions GROUP BY UID
```

This is not exactly "per column", but it's as far as you can get AFAIK. MySQL does not support real pivot tables.

Comment: That worked perfectly

SELECT DISTINCT `phpc_users`.`username`,`phpc_category_permissions`.`uid`, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `phpc_category_permissions`.`catid` ORDER BY `phpc_category_permissions`.`catid`) AS child_id_list
 FROM `phpc_category_permissions`
LEFT JOIN `phpc_users`
ON `phpc_category_permissions`.`uid` = `phpc_users`.`uid`
ORDER BY `phpc_users`.`uid`

Also good to note if you get [BLOB ] to click +options and check the show Blob contents